# Windows Installer installs older version

Tags: wpf, windows-installer, windows-server-2008

I am trying to install newer version of an application to client PC which has Windows Server 2008. But after installation when I run, it shows me output of older version. Even the log file is not updating newer texts.

I tried the same setups in other PCs in my office, they all get the newer version and output.

Are any residues or traces of older version preventing overwriting of newer version ? This is first time I see such kind of an issue.

Comment: do you use a bootstrapper that extracts your MSI and then runs it? If so, make sure you delete the contents of the extraction folder, in case files with the same name are found in it, so you don't actually run the old extracted MSI

Comment: No I run directly the MSI file.